# Where can I find XviD preset files for avconv?

Tags: video, files, avconv

I cannot seem to find any XviD preset files for avconv. I looked into `/usr/share/avconv` but there is none. I also googled alot but cannot seem to find any. I managed to compile one by looking at the manpages of avconv:

```
cmp=chroma
g=12
mbd=rd
me_method=umh
mpeg_quant=2
trellis=2
```

PS. I do NOT want any advice on any other codec like h264. I am specifically trying to create an XviD file.

Comment: This probably belongs on video.se more than ubuntu one.